# Ajax GET parameters not populated on Nginx

Tags: ajax, nginx, laravel-5

I am on a Laravel project that works perfectly locally (GET, POST requests on forms as well as Ajax). The hard part is when I deploy it on nginx, everything works except Ajax calls. I simply don't have parameters passed to my controllers. I would have something like

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: '{{route('
  test.route ') }}',
  data: {
    valuepassed: 5
  },
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
  }
})
```

with a controller returning the value passed like `return Input::get('valuepassed')`  or `return $request->valuepassed`. I get the value when running it locally but when on nginx the param is empty.
Here is my config :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www/html/mydomain/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?query_string;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    }
```

PS: I'm kinda new to nginx

Comment: query_string should be `$query_string` ??

Comment: That is exactly what was missing, and i wasn't going to notice it. Thanks mate @TarunLalwani

Comment: You should put it as an answer, i'll upvote @TarunLalwani

Answer (score 1):

You seems to have a typo in your config. Below

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?query_string;
```

should be

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
```

You are passing a fixed param instead of one that you get from client. Changing `query_string` to `$query_string` should fix it